# select max of mixed string/int column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table who returns me a value as bellow

```
             id_unique                name    serie      timeB    timeD
155488EA-FF70-49D7-99AB-AFD4125F3435  dell  14296188    05:51   06:19   
1B640883-0DB6-4255-B1ED-770B6578064C  dell  14295943    04:37   04:39
```

I want the `max` of the value i have tried a sql  as bellow :

```
 select max(cast(id_unique as varchar(36))),
max(name),max(serie),max(timeB),max(timeD) from mytable group by name
```

i got this result

```
1B640883-0DB6-4255-B1ED-770B6578064C  dell  14296188    05:51   06:19
```

But the result that i need is this one :

```
155488EA-FF70-49D7-99AB-AFD4125F3435  dell  14296188    05:51   06:19
```

This any metho to fix that ?

Comment: the max of **what** value?. And can you at least give names to the columns of your table?

Comment: You have enough points that you should know this question does not have anywhere near enough information for anybody to give you much help. Do you want the max of each column? The top 1 based on some mysterious criteria?

Comment: i added more details

Comment: @downloaddowload and yet, you failed to explain the max what value you want

Comment: You say that you want an answer...unfortunately what you actually need is a question. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If these are really stored as strings, I'm guessing that you want to cast the first column as a `uniqueidentifier` before finding the max, otherwise they will be evaluated alphabetically.

**SQL Server 2012 and above**

You can directly get the min/max of uniqueidentifiers:

```
select max(cast(id_unique as uniqueidentifier))
from MyTable
```

**Previous Versions**

You should cast as binary(16) before finding the min/max. I'm then casting back to uniqueidentifier for readability of the results:

```
select cast(max(cast(cast(id_unique as uniqueidentifier) as binary(16))) as uniqueidentifier)
from MyTable
```

Comment: actually i go this message `Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for max operator`

Comment: @downloaddowload good call; I had only tried it on a newer version of SQL Server. Please check the update.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want something like this using `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by somevalue desc) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
```

Where `somevalue` is the column you need the `max` of.  I presume you are currently trying to use `max` for every field -- that would explain your output...

Comment: It wasn't me, but I understand why they did it to us.

Comment: @TimLehner -- for someone to downvote somebody who attempts to answer a question without leaving a comment why shouldn't be allowed on this site imho...

Comment: That debate will probably rage on forever.

Comment: Not my downvote, but there are dozens of meta posts about commenting when you do downvote. For instance, from [Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252314/519216)